# What is the Ruby idiom for appending an element to an array that may not be initialized yet?

Tags: ruby, arrays, append, idioms

I found that `<<` can not be used by Array unless it has already been initialized. I currently write it like this:

```
unless @app
 @app = my_array
else
 @app << my_array
end
```

Is there a better way to write this?

I used ||= before, but

```
(@app ||= []) << [1,2,3]
```

will return [[1, 2, 3]], that's not we want. We want [1, 2, 3]

Comment: what is xxx?? is that array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you are using << wrong? << is meant for an element of the array, not a chunk of an array.

```
@app ||= []
@app.concat my_array
```

Comment: Thanks, ohter guys also give me good answers, but concat is really I want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a shortcut here

```
(@app ||= []) << xxx
```

### Edit:

If you want to push arrays to your `@app` variable, then using `concat` is a better option:

```
(@app ||= []).concat [1, 2, 3]
(@app ||= []).concat [4, 5, 6]

@app # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Alternatively, you can use the splat operator, as suggested by @ck3g.

Comment: @harryz: but so will your original code. If `@app` is already initialized, then `<<` will push `my_array` to it, which will result in a nested array.

Answer (score 2):

```
> (@app ||= []).push *[1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

The `*` is "unarray" operator.

```
> array = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
> [*array]
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

The methods `<<` and `push` differ in that `push` can take more than one argument.

And that also will work with single value:

```
> (@app2 ||= []).push *1
=> [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idiom:

```
@app ||= []
@app << xxx
```